# Dual booting 18.04 with 2 SSDs: swap file or partition?

Tags: dual-boot, swap

setting up dual boot with Dell 7820, 64gb ram, 2 2tb SSDs, Win10 workstation installed on SSD #1. Want to put Ubuntu 18.04 on SSD #2.

I understand 18.04 does not use a swap partition but rather a swap file. Still, some instructions I found said if you have a fast SSD or small ram you can set up a swap partition. I sometimes exceed my RAM and get a memory error under windows. Should I set up a swap partition, or swap file? I plan to devote 3x my RAM (64gb) = 200gb to swap, whether file or partition. This will still leave 1.8tb for root and home. I often use up my 64gb RAM and will be doing new things that would need vastly more RAM.

I've read other posts suggested, and it seems swap files are the default now because a swap partition is hard on an SSD. Seems confusing to me because swap is swap? Both will be on the #2 SSD. How do the two work differently?

If there is a way to make the 2 tb SSDs last longer it would be good.

Help understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much,

Jim

Comment: Just use the default, swapfile, and no need to set any size. It's managed automatically by the system. And in any case 3xRAM for a swap partition is an absurd, with 64GB of RAM you're likely to to never use swap!

Comment: Thanks Gabrial. I thought swap, or virtual memory, acts as additional ram. So when my 64gb RAM is full, if I have 200gb swap, I basically have 264gb RAM. I know it's hard to believe but I could easily fill a tb of RAM with what I do. So am I wrong in thinking that swap = RAM?

Comment: With what you do in Windows maybe (I don't know how but I'll take your word for it), but not likely to happen in Linux. And swapping should be avoided as it's much slower than RAM (even in a SSD), it's not really "more RAM", it's there to prevent apps or the whole system to crash due to lack of resources. If you need that much memory than by all means procure more RAM. But I could almost bet you don't ;)

Comment: use zram or zswap instead of a swap file or partition. [RAM alternative to swap partion or swap file on an SSD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/360654/44425)

Comment: Gabriel, 30 subjects in an EEG experiment, maybe 100. 4 gigs each. When loaded into EEGLAB, occupy about 10 gigs each. Many procesisng and analysis steps later, maybe 20-30 gigs/subject. Doing an analysis requires loading everything at once. Of course, for obvious reasons, the software has the ability to load one subject at a time, as needed, dump it, get the next subject.....  but this is much slower and getting through a full array of analyses can take months already. So, yeah, I can easily slam my 64 gb. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Thanks phuclv, have not heard of that and will check it out.

Comment: It's Gabriela and I'm a girl :) You're probably not used to it but here I am.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia re: "Just use the default, swapfile, and no need to set any size. It's managed automatically by the system"... if I read this correctly... this is absolutely incorrect. Size matters in this case.

Comment: @heynnema Since Swapfile it's the default in Ubuntu I never had to choose any size for it during installation. Does it have a fixed maximum size? Could be but it doesn't make sense if it is.

Comment: @river251 re: " I thought swap, or virtual memory, acts as additional ram"... swap is NOT RAM. In brief... swap is used by the system to store bits and pieces of RAM that aren't immediately needed. With 64G RAM, and large data sets, you may need to tweak your vm.swappiness parameter to optimize RAM usage vs SWAP usage.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia the /swapfile gets created during FRESH installs. If however, during an UPGRADE, a previous swap partition exists, it uses that instead of /swapfile. In either case, properly sizing swap depends on a number of factors, including RAM size, and expected RAM usage. I could talk about it for hours, as most people don't understand how to use swap. Too little swap is bad, but too much swap is a waste of space. Sizing, and tuning the vm.swappiness parameter, are always important.

Comment: @heynnema True, but I do understand swap. And the question is not about an upgrade anyway :)

Comment: @river251 a 200G swap file/partition is insane, and not necessary. If you're really using that much RAM, adding more RAM is the proper solution, vs adding an oversized swap space. Also, a swap partition is not better/worse than a /swapfile on a SSD/HDD. And, there's nothing wrong with setting up more that one /swapfile (or partition).

Comment: @river251 don't use zram or zswap. Just properly size RAM and SWAP, tune vm.swappiness if required, and let the system take care of things.

Comment: Gabriella, I'm so sorry, yes you're right, always assume male-only in tech contexts. Very happy to be mistaken. Here at NMSU the CS department is a pioneer with Young Women in Computing Program. Very sorry for my mis-assumption. Or, mr-assumption.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications on RAM vs swap. Swap <> RAM. Ok.

Comment: Gabriella, then I don't need to create a swap partition with U 18.04. When I install it, do I have to create or activate or size the swap file? Or is it automatically just "there" and it just "works"?

Comment: And swap will grow as big as needed to hold pages from RAM? Even if it's huge?

Comment: @river251 no, swap will NOT grow as big as needed to hold pages from RAM. Swap only uses up to the max size of the /swapfile or swap partition, but that's no reason to create a huge /swapfile or swap partition. Planning for a /swapfile comes from a combination of RAM size, RAM utilitzation, vm.swappiness settings, and the size of the /swapfile. I'd set your /swapfile or swap partition to 16G, test your system, and monitor RAM and swap usage. Then we can decide either to add RAM, increase /swapfile, or tinker with vm.swappiness.

Comment: @river251 postnote... if you believe that you're running out of memory when running under Windows, you might check the size of the pagefile (similar to /swapfile in Ubuntu).